# insert greek letter in enumerate list

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, greek, alphabet

When I type `\alpha` my list get crazy...What I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Serif}
  \def\Hello{Welcome! \fontspec{WenQuanYi Micro Hei} 你好!}
\else\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
  \def\Hello{Welcome!}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{bla bla bla (\alpha , Q) bla bla blabla bla bla};
\item bla bla bla (\alfa, Q);
\item bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need to place `\alpha` in math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item bla bla bla $(\alpha, Q)$ bla bla blabla bla bla};
  \item bla bla bla $(\alpha, Q)$;
  \item bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note that there is no `\alfa`, unless you define it (say) using

```
\let\alfa\alpha
```

in your preamble.

Answer (score 1):

do you have tried using $\alpha $?